# Transforming data that is too long

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot

I am currently trying to pivot my data as it is too long to graph in ggplot - I have attached an image of it.

The data set is from the `flexclust` package in r. It is the `milk` data set. The animal names are set to rows and it has 5 columns being the nutrients- water, protein etc.

I am trying to set it up to do a ggplot stacked % bar chart. I think the best way would be to have it so that there is 3 columns: the animal names repeated 5 times, the nutrients stacked and the values as a third column.

So it would look a little like this:

```
Animal Nutrient Value

Hippo Water     90.4
Hippo Protein    0.6
Hippo Fat
Hippo Lactose
Hippo
Donkey                  etc.
```

The trouble is I am really struggling to come up with the code to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rosie

to pivot my data so that it is wider

Comment: Hi OP.  Please, [see the guidelines on creating a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on your question.  Right away, I'm confused when you mention the data is "too long".  What do you mean by this?  How large is your dataset?  The `ggplot2` package is built around [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), so setting up the wide format of data is the reverse of what you typically want to do prior to plotting with `ggplot2`.  Please, provide more information and a reprex.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is actually a `pivot_longer`. Stacking the animal names moves the data from "wide" to "long". Wide means fewer rows and more columns, while long means fewer columns and more rows.

Here is the code:

```
library(flexclust)
data(milk)

milk %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(water, protein, fat, lactose, ash)) %>% 
  rename(Animal = rowname, Nutrient = name, Value = value)

#> # A tibble: 125 × 3
#>    Animal    Nutrient Value
#>    <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 HORSE     water    90.1 
#>  2 HORSE     protein   2.6 
#>  3 HORSE     fat       1   
#>  4 HORSE     lactose   6.9 
#>  5 HORSE     ash       0.35
#>  6 ORANGUTAN water    88.5 
#>  7 ORANGUTAN protein   1.4 
#>  8 ORANGUTAN fat       3.5 
#>  9 ORANGUTAN lactose   6   
#> 10 ORANGUTAN ash       0.24
#> # ℹ 115 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

From here, it should be easy to plot as described!

Note that you can also rename the columns without the explicit last step. You could do this by:

```
milk %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Animal") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(water, protein, fat, lactose, ash),
    names_to = "Nutrient",
    values_to = "Value"
  )

#> # A tibble: 125 × 3
#>    Animal    Nutrient Value
#>    <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 HORSE     water    90.1 
#>  2 HORSE     protein   2.6 
#>  3 HORSE     fat       1   
#>  4 HORSE     lactose   6.9 
#>  5 HORSE     ash       0.35
#>  6 ORANGUTAN water    88.5 
#>  7 ORANGUTAN protein   1.4 
#>  8 ORANGUTAN fat       3.5 
#>  9 ORANGUTAN lactose   6   
#> 10 ORANGUTAN ash       0.24
#> # ℹ 115 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```